# Make Python code open in a simple window on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I wrote some simple Python code which prints out a few lines of text every minute. I want to keep it open on my desktop, kind of like a live ticker. Is there a way to open the code in a new window which doesn't have a blinking cursor and takes up as little space as possible?

Comment: You should look into some UI libraries to create a custom UI. That will give you complete control of what the window shows.

Comment: Alright, will try to do that.